# How do I extract useful information from the payload of a GADT / existential type?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, gadt, existential-type, menhir

I'm trying to use [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/)'s [incremental parsing API](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec60) and [introspection API](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec62)s in a generated parser. I want to, say, determine the *semantic value* associated with a particular LR(1) stack entry; i.e. a token that's been previously consumed by the parser.

Given an abstract parsing checkpoint, encapsulated in Menhir's type `'a env`, I can extract a “stack element” from the LR automaton; it looks like this:

> ```ml
> type element =
>   | Element: 'a lr1state * 'a * position * position -> element
> ```
>
> The type element describes one entry in the stack of the LR(1) automaton. In a stack element of the form `Element (s, v, startp, endp)`, `s` is a (non-initial) state and `v` is a semantic value. The value `v` is associated with the incoming symbol A of the state `s`. In other words, the value `v` was pushed onto the stack just before the state `s` was entered. Thus, for some type `'a`, the state `s` has type `'a lr1state` and the value `v` has type `'a` ...
>
> In order to do anything useful with the value `v`, one must gain information about the type `'a`, by inspection of the state `s`. So far, the type `'a lr1state` is abstract, so there is no way of inspecting `s`. The inspection API (§9.3) offers further tools for this purpose.

Okay, cool! So I go and dive into the inspection API:

> The type 'a terminal is a generalized algebraic data type (GADT). A value of type 'a terminal represents a terminal symbol (without a semantic value). The index 'a is the type of the semantic values associated with this symbol ...
>
> ```ml
> type _ terminal =
> | T_A : unit terminal
> | T_B : int terminal
> ```
>
> The type 'a nonterminal is also a GADT. A value of type 'a nonterminal represents a nonterminal symbol (without a semantic value). The index 'a is the type of the semantic values associated with this symbol ...
>
> ```ml
> type _ nonterminal =
> | N_main : thing nonterminal
> ```

Piecing these together, I get something like the following (where "command" is one of my grammar's nonterminals, and thus `N_command` is a `string nonterminal`):

```ml
let current_command (env : 'a env) =
   let rec f i =
      match Interpreter.get i env with
      | None -> None
      | Some Interpreter.Element (lr1state, v, _startp, _endp) ->
      match Interpreter.incoming_symbol lr1state with
      | Interpreter.N Interpreter.N_command -> Some v
      | _ -> f (i + 1)
   in
   f 0
```

Unfortunately, this is puking up very confusing type-errors for me:

```
File "src/incremental.ml", line 110, characters 52-53:
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         string
       This instance of string is ambiguous:
       it would escape the scope of its equation
```

This is a bit above my level! I'm pretty sure I understand why I *can't* do what I tried to do above; but I don't understand what my alternatives are. In fact, the Menhir manual specifically mentions this complexity:

> This function can be used to gain access to the semantic value `v` in a stack element `Element (s, v, _, _)`. Indeed, by case analysis on the symbol `incoming_symbol s`, one gains information about the type `'a`, hence one obtains the ability to do something useful with the value `v`.

Okay, but that's what I thought I *did*, above: case-analysis by `match`'ing on `incoming_symbol s`, pulling out the case where `v` is of a single, specific type: `string`.

tl;dr: how do I extract the string payload from this GADT, and do something useful with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your error sounds like

> This instance of string is ambiguous:
>     it would escape the scope of its equation

it means that the type checker is not really sure if outside of the pattern matching branch the type of `v` should be a string, or another type that is equal to `string` but only inside the branch. You just need to add a type annotation when leaving the branch to remove this ambiguity:

```
 | Interpreter.(N N_command) -> Some (v:string)
```